# For testing update functions in Elm that use Files in their Msg, how can I create a File value to pass in test? Can you somehow create a File fuzzer?

Tags: file, testing, elm

For example, I have this model:

```
import File exposing (File)

type alias Model =
{ selectedFiles : Dict String File
, fileUploadInfoList : List FileUploadInfo
, modalSelectedFile : Maybe File
... 
}

type Msg
= SelectedFiles String (List File)
| Upload Int
| UploadedFiles (Result Http.Error (List FileInfo))
| DownloadedFile String (Result Http.Error Bytes.Bytes)
| DownloadFile FileInfo
| LoadedFiles (Result Http.Error (List FileInfo))
| OpenModal { startFocusOn : String, returnFocusTo : String } FileInfo
| ModalMsg Modal.Msg
| Focus String
| Dismiss
| DismissModal
| SelectModalFile (List File)
| UpdateFile
| UpdatedFile (Result Http.Error FileInfo)
```

And in update function:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> { token : String, apiBaseUrl : String } -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model apiParams =
case msg of
    SelectedFiles key [ file ] ->
        ( { model | selectedFiles = Dict.insert key file model.selectedFiles }, Cmd.none )
    ...
```

When I write tests for this update function how do I call it in the test? The dictionary value is of type File. How do I create a test file? What to put for [ file ] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` is an [opaque type](https://elm-radio.com/episode/intro-to-opaque-types/), meaning that it can't be created outside of the module where it's defined. In this case, there isn't a way to create a `File` value in a test environment, because the only ways that the package exposes to create a value are via a `Cmd` or via a `Decoder`, and [that decoder won't work in node.js](https://github.com/elm/file/blob/1.0.5/src/Elm/Kernel/File.js#L16-L21).

If you want to be able to test this message, you will need to use a different type in the message. You can move your logic that converts a `File` into a `FileInfo` into your event handler, so that the message only deals with `FileInfo`.

[elm-program-test](https://github.com/avh4/elm-program-test/) provides shim types to support testing `Cmd` values, but [does not](https://github.com/avh4/elm-program-test/issues/46) [yet](https://github.com/avh4/elm-program-test/issues/47) [support](https://github.com/avh4/elm-program-test/issues/48) `File`.